# Query Criteria Inquiry

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query accepting input from a form. The issue I have right now is I am trying to account for an empty criteria. Basically a criteria to catch all instances of the occurrences. How do I achieve this?

For example, there is a field on the qry1 called sex. On the form1 called txtSex. I can catch cases of Male and Female easy. But I need a way to catch All(Male, Females and Empty cells). This is the syntax in my query [Forms]![form1]![txtSex]

Comment: show your sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So , if user not select any option from Sex checkbox and you are treated like All then to handle this do not add filter in sql query if checkbox is empty.

Sample Pseudo Code will be

```
if(txtSex != "")
 sqlquery = "select * from tbl where sex = txtSex.selectedvalue"
else
 sqlquery = "select * from tbl"
```

Comment: You logic directed me to the answer. Had like a lapse there , I just added an if statement to the check for * situations. Did the job. Hope that makes sense.